# how to make an attribute in the following call optional (ie allow nil)

Tags: ios, swift

A long time since I have written iOS code but I have the following Model in an iOS app and works great but now we are finding out that `detail` is optional and we should allow nil values. How would I adjust the initializer to support this? Sorry, I find the optionals a bit difficult to grasp (concept makes sense - executing it is difficult).

```
class Item{
  var id:Int
  var header:String
  var detail:String

  init?(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    guard let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int,
      let header = dictionary["header"] as? String,
      let detail = dictionary["detail"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    self.id = id
    self.header = header
    self.detail = detail
  }
```

and creating:

```
var items = [Item]()
if let item = Item(dictionary: dictionary) {
  self.items.append(item)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in above answer by @AMomchilov, you could assign the value only if it exists in your `init` method.
But also you could check for the value and then access it like below:

```
class Item {
    var id:Int
    var header:String
    var detail: String?

    init?(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        guard let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int,
            let header = dictionary["header"] as? String else {
                return nil
        }
        self.id = id
        self.header = header
        self.detail = dictionary["detail"] as? String //if there is value then it will assign else nil will be assigned.
    }
}

let dictionary = ["id": 10, "header": "HeaderValue"]
var items = [Item]()
if let item = Item(dictionary: dictionary) {
    items.append(item)

    print(item.id)
    print(item.detail ?? "'detail' is nil for this item")
    print(item.header)
}else{
    print("No Item created!")
}
```

And the console is :

```
10
'detail' is nil for this item
HeaderValue
```

And if there is `detail' value present then:

```
let dictionary = ["id": 10, "header": "HeaderValue", "detail":"DetailValue"]
var items = [Item]()
if let item = Item(dictionary: dictionary) {
    items.append(item)

    print(item.id)
    print(item.detail ?? "'detail' is nil for this item")
    print(item.header)
}else{
    print("No Item created!")
}
```

Console:

```
10
DetailValue
HeaderValue
```

Comment: I forgot the `as?` can just return nil like that! This is very nice, have an up boat

Comment: You could accept the answer whichever helped to fix your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `detail` from the guard (as now a `nil` value is acceptable), and assign `self.detail` to `dictionary["detail"] as? String`.

```
class Item {
  var id: Int
  var header: String
  var detail: String?

  init?(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    guard let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int,
      let header = dictionary["header"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    self.id = id
    self.header = header

    self.detail = dictionary["detail"] as? String
  }
```

Edit: Improved based on Santosh's answer.